# device not recognized in network

Tags: privacy, firewalls

On my windows 8 Computer I sometimes can see a device in the network view , which I can't identify as one of mine. See following screenshot:
[image]

For me this looks like a network breach. How can I analyse this issue or prevent devices to access my private network ?
Or does someone recognize this device as a service ?

Comment: Solution: disable WPS on your router.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a rogue device but not necessarily.

Or the PC is seeing a device and it’s associated service incorrectly.

You could start by checking your routers DHCP to see what devices it has issued IPs to.

If you still can’t see it then download a network scanner app. I use ‘fing’ onthe IPhone. But there are others for iOS and other OS. Make sure your phone is on the same network as your PC and then scan. These apps will attempt to find all devices and services (attempt to).

Answer (score 1):

Google thinks this is a Android device, a Tinno P4601AN.

As far as I can see, it’s a [smartphone](http://smartgsmphone.com/en1/artlite.htm).

If you are unsure about which device it is and if it is legitimately on your home network, you  could:

- check your routers web interface to see if it is connected wirelessly or via LAN
- change your wireless password and have it gone,
- ask your family about what devices they use.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already checked with the family. No Wiko-Android Device in use. I checked the web interface, but the device is already gone at that time. But thanks anyway it confirms me the way howto analyse the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest changing your wifi passphrase as a minimum, You could also set up a MAC whitelist on your router.